# How to wait a loop in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in angular and trying to do some loop operation in firebase. I want to fetch all the information by email id.

```
user_info = [];
 for (let index = 0; index < this.email.length; index++) {
          this.get_student_service
            .get_student_by_email_id(this.email[index])
            .subscribe((res) => {
              this.user_info.push(res);
              console.log(this.user_info);
            });
        }
        console.log(this.user_info);
```

output:-[image: Here is my output]

But I want print user_info after loop complete there execution

Comment: It is a no-go and bad practice to "wait" in a web application for returning from a request. Maybe it is also not what you want. Can you be more specific for your use case? I guess printing the email information is not what you really want to do in the end?

Comment: I want to print my whole collection after the loop execution

Answer (score 0):

Fork Join will resolve your problem I guess, please try it out.

```
forkJoin(
    this.email.map(email => this.get_student_service.get_student_by_email_id(email)
)
.subscribe(res => {
    console.log(this.user_info); // will print result as an array
})
```

Comment: Nothing is printing

Comment: `forkJoin( this.email.map((email) =>
            this.get_student_service.get_student_by_email_id(email))).subscribe((res) => {
          console.log(res);})`   I Try something like this

Comment: `let data = this.email.map((email) => this.get_student_service.get_student_by_email_id(email)
 let obs = forkJoin([data]); obs.subscribe((res) => {console.log(res);
  })console.log('Execute');});`      output:- [Observable]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `for` loop you could use the `map` method of the email `array` and then use an `Observable.forkJoin` to handle all the results at the same time.

Something like this:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

const getStudentsRequests = this.email.map(email =>     
    this.get_student_service.get_student_by_email_id(email);
);

forkJoin(getStudentsRequests).subscribe(resultArray => (this.user_info = resultArray));
```

Comment: It gives me a like **Property 'forkJoin' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'**

Comment: Instead of `Observable.forkJoin(...` use only `forkJoin(...` and import it from `rxjs`, like this:

`import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: sir can you check this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908123/unable-to-subscribe-after-forkjoin